# SQLite: No Column Names In Output of Select Statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am new to SQLite and trying to work my way through the basics. The problem is when I give it a simple command:

```
select * from newTable;
```

The output is as follows:

```
GoodState|GoodCapital
ShittyState|Raleigh
```

Which does not provide the column names on the output. My column names are: `State` and `State_Capital`

Is there any option available to make the column names show up on the top of the columns outputted like in MySql?

Answer (score 3):

Oh. My bad. I should've googled more thoroughly.

The answer is:

```
.headers on
```

This enabled column headers in output.

Answer (score 0):

Please, if I may be allowed to supplement the answer with the command-line alternative:

```
sqlite3 -noheader foo.db "select * from newTable"
```